# Javascript table using this for objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Library</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>My Library Book List</h1>
    <p>This is my simple library project using object oriented javascript.</p>
    <p id="myBooks"></p>

    <br>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
    <label for="author">Author:</label>
    <input type="text" id="author" name="author"><br>
    <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pages" name="pages"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>       
<script>
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener
    ("click", function(event){event.preventDefault()
    });
</script>

<br>

<table>
    <tr>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>author</th>
      <th>pages</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="title"></td>
      <td id="author"></td>
      <td id="pages"></td>
     </tr>
      </table><br>
      

<button onclick="window.location.href='/myForm.html';">
    New myBooks</button>





    <script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

```
const bookArray = [
    
];

function Book(author, title, pages){
    // the constructor
    this.author = author
    this.title = title
    this.pages = pages
}


function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages) {
    this.title = title
    this.author = author
    this.pages = pages
    this.myArray = []

    this.addArray = function(){
        this.myArray.push({ title, author, pages });
        return this.myArray
    }

    this.printArray = function() {
        var result = "";
        for ( let key in this.myArray) {
            return this.myArray[key]
            result =+ this.myArray[key];
        }
        return result
    }

    this.toHTML = function() {
        document.getElementById("myBooks").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this.myArray);
        return JSON.stringify(this.myArray)
    }    


    this.updateTable = function() {
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = this.title;
    }


}


let store1 = new addBookToLibrary("Cat and hat", "Bob", 150);
```

I am expected the function to updateTable to add table data to my html or need a way to statically display each object of book in my table.

Everything I made with this.parameter has been working up to this point. Can i use 'this' reference to display data in my table? I would prefer the table just populate as soons as a object is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use `this` in your HTML for this purpose, you can do it simply in your JS code. You can use the following code for this purpose. I have used the same HTML code but modified with the use of `this` keyword.

```js
const bookArray = [];

function Book(author, title, pages) {

  this.author = author;
  this.title = title;
  this.pages = pages;
}

function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages) {
  const book = new Book(author, title, pages);
  bookArray.push(book);
  return book;
}

function updateTable() {

  const table = document.getElementById("myBooks");

  table.innerHTML = "";

  for (const book of bookArray) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.innerHTML = `
      <td>${book.title}</td>
      <td>${book.author}</td>
      <td>${book.pages}</td>
    `;
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
}


document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  const title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  const author = document.getElementById("author").value;
  const pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;


  const book = addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages);


  updateTable();


  event.preventDefault();
});


updateTable();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Library</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>My Library Book List</h1>
    <p>This is my simple library project using object oriented javascript.</p>
    <p id="myBooks"></p>

    <br>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
    <label for="author">Author:</label>
    <input type="text" id="author" name="author"><br>
    <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pages" name="pages"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>       
<script>
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener
    ("click", function(event){event.preventDefault()
    });
</script>

<br>

<table>
    <tr>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>author</th>
      <th>pages</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="title"></td>
      <td id="author"></td>
      <td id="pages"></td>
     </tr>
      </table><br>
      

<button onclick="window.location.href='/myForm.html';">
    New myBooks</button>





    <script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

```
updateTable();
```

Comment: Thanks i will try the code without "THIS"

Comment: Thanks after removing the "This" from the code I was able to complete the task.